# Laravel "auth controller not found" exception

Tags: laravel-routing

I am making admin panel in LARAVEL4.2.*. I make the controller in "admin" folder and also a view in views "admin" folder. My controller code is

```
namespace admin;

class AuthController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }


}
```

and my routes coding is:

```
Route::get('admin/login',   array('as' => 'admin.login',       'uses' => 'App\Controllers\Admin\AuthController@getLogin'));
```

I have also tried "composer update" and "composer dump-autoload" above 50 times. My url is localhost/laraveltest/public/admin/login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your namespace as `admin`, therefore you have to use this also in your routes:

```
 Route::get('admin/login', array('uses' => '\admin\AuthController@getLogin'));
```

Comment: Seems you kind of messed up your namespaces. For starters, try to remove any namespaces from your controllers and routes and run $ composer dump-autoload.